# cloud endpoints jsonp [google cloud computing]

Tags: jsonp, google-cloud-endpoints

I am searching for anything that clearly states whether you can have Cloud Endpoint APIs return JSONP instead of JSON (or any other format for that matter)?

If not, how would you deal with x-domain calls, thinking of the usual JS libraries? I am aware there is a JS library you can use, however chances are you want to manage that part on your own without another JS library in the mix.

Cheers
z4c

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. Only JSON is [currently supported](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/#h.hl6cwmm8921n).
2. Just use the [JavaScript client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js).